# Copy Worksheet not functioning

Tags: excel, vba, copy

My attached code is causing an error when trying to copy over the worksheet into the new workbook, can anyone advise what might be driving this problem?

```
Sub Excel1()

   Dim rngLoopRange As Range
   Dim wsSummary As Worksheet
   Dim rngDealers As Worksheet

   Set wsSummary = Sheets("PL")

   For Each rngLoopRange In Worksheets("AUX").Range("A1:A38")
      wsSummary.Range("C12").Value = rngLoopRange.Value

    Application.Run "TM1REFRESH"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsSummary.Range("C12").Value
    ws.Copy before:=wb.Worksheets(1)
    wb.Close savechanges:=True


Next rngLoopRange

Set wsSummary = Nothing

    MsgBox "Complete!", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: It's best to include your error and the line causing it within your question, otherwise it is hard to determine which part might be wrong. Not doing so could potentially get you [downvoted](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't defined `ws` so it's not copying anything. Using `Option Explicit` at the top of your module helps avoid such mistakes.

Comment: `Option Explicit` strikes again.

Comment: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and you will never forget `Option Explicit` again.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ what a hot tip, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.